# exim virtual domains vs main domain - rewriting rules

Tags: freebsd, exim

I currently have two servers

- `first.mydomain.com` (ip:A.B.C.28) and
- `second.mydomain.com` (ip:A.B.C.30)

Both servers have DNS and reverse dns entries, e.g. A.B.C.30 -> `second.mydomain.com`

The `first.mydomain.com` - handles all emails from/to the mydomain.com (e.g. the **MX** for `mydomain.com` pointing to `first.mydomain.com`)

The `second` is configured (exim/dovecot) for handling emails for two other domains. (`virt1.com` and `virt2.com`). **MX** records are OK,
`virt1.com mail is handled by 100 second.mydomain.com`

All basic things works (TLS, dovecot-auth.. etc..) Receiving email is OK to - delivering into `/home/mail/virt1.com/user/Maildir`. Outgoing mail is delivering too (but strange), so routers, and transports works, but:

For example, when: the `user@virt1.com` sending email to `someuser@example.com` via `second.mydomain.com`, got strange things in the headers.

```
Return-Path: <"user@virt1.com"@mydomain.com>
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ??? - added mydomain
Received: ... deleted ...
Received: ... deleted ...
Received: from somedsl.someisp.com ([X.X.X.X]:21563 helo=marvin.local)
    by second.mydomain.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:256)
    (Exim 4.80.1 (FreeBSD))
    (envelope-from <"user@virt1.com"@second.mydomain.com>)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ??? added FQDN
    id 1UVf91-000ALf-fb
    for someuser@example.com; Fri, 26 Apr 2013 11:40:43 +0200
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 11:40:42 +0200
From: username <user@virt1.com>
Reply-To: user@virt1.com
To: someuser@example.com
Subject: test message
Sender: "user@virt1.com"@second.mydomain.com
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ??? added the FQDN again
```

start of my exim config is:

```
local_interfaces = A.B.C.30
primary_hostname = second.mydomain.com
domainlist local_domains = dsearch;/etc/mail/virtual #each domain has its own subdir
```

Yet, haven't any rewriting rules.

Questions:

- should i set the `smtp_active_hostname` to something, instead of `second.mydomain.com`?
- need setup some heeader rewiting rules? (probably yes)
- what else i should check?
- some idea how to rid off the above weird headers?

The above is running in one freebsd jail, but it probably doesn't matter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first mail servers (of which Exim is derived from a very early one) were designed at a time when it was common for an email address for userX@example.com to belong to a real unix user named "userX".  As such, when it constructs the Sender header and other headers, it would use the username @ default_domainname.  The username part is referred to in Exim as the local_part.

In modern systems, it is much more common to have virtual users, where an exim server can receive email to a domain that is not the default domain, and the local_part is likely not a valid local user, or there may be multiple email addresses all with the same local_part.  In systems like this, instead of authenticating as "userX", it's more common to authenticate as "userX@example.com".  Exim internally will treat that whole string as the username unless you configure it otherwise.

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-message_processing.html#SECTsubmodnon

The `control = submission` line tells exim to apply certain fixups to the message that gets submitted, including creating those headers you mentioned.  Change it to:

`control = submission/sender_retain`

to indicate that you want Exim to treat the submitted name as the full userX@example.com instead of just the local_part, meaning exim won't try to append the default domain name to what was submitted.  The exim documentation linked above has a lot of great detail on this whole message submission and fixup process.

Comment: unfortunately i can upvote only once! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :) :)